# Como soluciono "Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object" en una consulta LEFT JOIN?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Tengo mi tabla hecha con AJAX en donde puedo editar y eliminar las filas que tengo en ellas, dejo el codigo abajo donde funciona a la perfeccion con una consulta LEFT JOIN, consulta que requiero replicar en el vaciado de mi formulario del modal que presento más abajo.

```
<?php

include "conexion.php";

$user_id=null;
$sql1= "SELECT recepcion.id, recepcion.id_diagnostico, recepcion.justificacion, recepcion.foliomuestra, 
recepcion.nolab, recepcion.institucion, recepcion.appaterno, recepcion.apmaterno, 
recepcion.nombre, recepcion.edad, recepcion.id_municipio, recepcion.sexo, recepcion.muestra, recepcion.fechatoma, 
recepcion.fechainicio, recepcion.fecharecep, recepcion.folioplat, recepcion.captura, 
diagnosticos.diagnostico, municipios.municipio FROM recepcion LEFT JOIN municipios 
ON recepcion.id_municipio = municipios.id LEFT JOIN diagnosticos 
ON recepcion.id_diagnostico = diagnosticos.id ORDER BY recepcion.id DESC";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>

<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <th>Diagnostico</th>
    <th>Justificacion</th>
    <th>FolioMuestra</th>
    <th>NoLAB</th>
    <th>Institucion</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Edad</th>
    <th>Municipio</th>
    <th>Fechas</th>
    <th></th>
</thead>
<?php while ($r=$query->fetch_array()):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $r["diagnostico"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["justificacion"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["foliomuestra"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["nolab"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["institucion"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["appaterno"]." ".$r["apmaterno"]."<br>".$r["nombre"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["edad"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["municipio"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "TOMA: ".$r["fechatoma"]."<br>INICIO: ".$r["fechainicio"]."<br>RECEP: ".$r["fecharecep"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:150px;">
        <a data-id="<?php echo $r["id"];?>" class="btn btn-edit btn-sm yellow-btn">Editar</a>
        <a href="#" id="del-<?php echo $r["id"];?>" class="btn btn-sm red-btn">Eliminar</a>
        <script>
        $("#del-"+<?php echo $r["id"];?>).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            p = confirm("Estas seguro?");
            if(p){
                $.get("./php/eliminar.php","id="+<?php echo $r["id"];?>,function(data){
                    loadTabla();
                });
            }

        });
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
</table>
<?php else:?>
    <p class="alert alert-warning">No hay resultados</p>
<?php endif;?>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <script>
    $(".btn-edit").click(function(){
        id = $(this).data("id");
        $.get("./php/formulario.php","id="+id,function(data){
            $("#form-edit").html(data);
        });
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
  <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Actualizar</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="form-edit"></div>
        </div>

      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

El problema de Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object surge solamente cuando en mi consulta para el modal uso el LEFT JOIN y doy clic en mi boton de Editar.

Cuando tengo la consulta del modal solamente de la siguiente forma no tengo el problema:

```
select * from recepcion where id = ".$_GET["id"]
```

El error sale cuando lo tengo así:

> FORMULARIO.PHP

```
<?php
    include "conexion.php";
    
    $user_id=null;
    $sql1= "select recepcion.id, recepcion.id_diagnostico, recepcion.justificacion, recepcion.foliomuestra, 
    recepcion.nolab, recepcion.institucion, recepcion.appaterno, recepcion.apmaterno, 
    recepcion.nombre, recepcion.edad, recepcion.id_municipio, recepcion.sexo, recepcion.muestra, recepcion.fechatoma, 
    recepcion.fechainicio, recepcion.fecharecep, recepcion.folioplat, recepcion.captura, 
    diagnosticos.diagnostico, municipios.municipio  from recepcion LEFT JOIN municipios 
    ON recepcion.id_municipio = municipios.id LEFT JOIN diagnosticos 
    ON recepcion.id_diagnostico = diagnosticos.id  where id = ".$_GET["id"];
    $query = $con->query($sql1);
    $person = null;
    if($query->num_rows>0){
    while ($r=$query->fetch_object()){
      $person=$r;
      break;
    }
    
      }
    ?>
    
    <?php if($person!=null):?>
    
    <form role="form" id="actualizar" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_diagnostico">Diagnostico</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->diagnostico; ?>" name="id_diagnostico" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="justificacion">Justificacion</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->justificacion; ?>" name="justificacion" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="foliomuestra">Folio Muestra</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->foliomuestra; ?>" name="foliomuestra" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nolab">No.Lab</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->nolab; ?>" name="nolab" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="institucion">Institucion</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->institucion; ?>" name="institucion" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="appaterno">Apellido Paterno</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->appaterno; ?>" name="appaterno" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="apmaterno">Apellido Materno</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->apmaterno; ?>" name="apmaterno" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $person->nombre; ?>" name="nombre" >
      </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $person->id; ?>">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Actualizar</button>
    </form>
    
    <script>
        $("#actualizar").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("./php/actualizar.php",$("#actualizar").serialize(),function(data){
        });
        //alert("Agregado exitosamente!");
        //$("#actualizar")[0].reset();
        $('#editModal').modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        loadTabla();
      });
    </script>
    
    <?php else:?>
      <p class="alert alert-danger">404 No se encuentra</p>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el error, era una cosa de nada, estaba usando left join, una estructura 'tabla'.'columna', y no me percate que en el where id al final de mi consulta no esta aplicada esa misma estructura.

De estar así (final de la consulta):

```
 "where id = ".$_GET["id"]";
```

Queda así:

```
"where recepcion.id = ".$_GET["id"]";



$sql1= "SELECT recepcion.id, recepcion.id_diagnostico, recepcion.justificacion, recepcion.foliomuestra, 
recepcion.nolab, recepcion.institucion, recepcion.appaterno, recepcion.apmaterno, 
recepcion.nombre, recepcion.edad, recepcion.id_municipio, recepcion.sexo, recepcion.muestra, recepcion.fechatoma, 
recepcion.fechainicio, recepcion.fecharecep, recepcion.folioplat, recepcion.captura, 
diagnosticos.diagnostico, municipios.municipio  FROM recepcion LEFT JOIN municipios 
ON recepcion.id_municipio = municipios.id LEFT JOIN diagnosticos 
ON recepcion.id_diagnostico = diagnosticos.id where recepcion.id = ".$_GET["id"];
```